# How can I variate multiple text values in multiple UITextFields consecutively?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for a way to find a more efficient way to variate my quotes onto a variety of UITextFields (in this case, donorView1, donorView2, etc.) after only one click of a UIButton. Clicking the Randomize button would result in an array of quotes, however, with this array of quotes, I can only get one quote per field, but I need various quotes in each box (i.e. donorView1 would have Letters DQ, A, DP, DR while donorView2 could have A, C, B, DP). I'm very new to this code – for this is my first time coding an iOS application – so if it's possible, please try to explain in simpler terms! I need at least 6 random letters per textfield.

```
@IBOutlet weak var patientView: UITextField!

@IBAction func patientFunction(sender: UIButton!) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var donorView1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var donorView2: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var donorView3: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var donorView4: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var donorView5: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var donorView6: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var donorView7: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var donorView8: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Randomize: UIButton!

@IBAction func Randomize(sender: UIButton!) {

    let quoteArray1 = [" -A,", " -B,", " -C,", " -DR,", " -DQ, ", " -DP,"]
    self.patientView.text = quoteArray1 [Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView1.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView1.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView2.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView3.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView4.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView5.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView6.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView7.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
    self.donorView8.text = quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))] + quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(quoteArray1.count)))]
}

   override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `IBOutletCollection` instead of `IBOutlet`?

Answer (score 0):

```
let textFields: [UITextField] = [self.patientView, self.donorView1, 2, 3, etc.] 
let quoteArray1 = [" -A,", " -B,", " -C,", " -DR,", " -DQ, ", " -DP,"]
let randomRange = UInt32(quoteArray1.count)
for textField in textFields {
    textField.text = quoteArray1 [Int(arc4random_uniform(randomRange))] + 
                quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(randomRange))] + 
                quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(randomRange))]
}
```

just a note on style that will save you in the long term, keep your outlets and actions in their own sections, and ditch the spacing between the outlets... :)

**Update:**

If you need to display each of the array elements in various sequences on all textfields, you should shuffle the array randomly and set the text with the concatenation of each array element. Shuffle the array for before setting each label.

Check this [Randomly shuffle a Swift array](http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/17/randomly-shuffle-a-swift-array/)

Comment: The problem with that is that my equation would be too complex to hold 6 quoteArray1[Int(arc4random_uniform(randomRange))]. I'm not sure how I could simplify my equation to make it able to build with 6, but thank you for the help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by too complex? What is your requirement? Should each textfield display a random sequence of each of the 6 quotes? If so, your best approach is to randomly shuffle the array, and use the array elements to build each textfield.text string. This is much better for performance and you could also break the 6 limit. I'll add a link to the answer.